# "Cannot find name" when using the ORDERBY DAX function

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I used the example [here](https://dax.do/5A25mXV5YHxDmp/) given in this [this article](https://dax.guide/index/) about the INDEX function to find the second top customer in my dashboard. The measure works fine, but for some reason when I reference the [@Amt] column it becomes grey and an error shows saying "Cannot find name". Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore the underline. INDEX() is a new function and sometimes it takes a couple of releases for the intellisense to catch up. Rest assured that the engine is interpreting your code perfectly fine.